# How to fetch data by foreign key

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys

I have seen this asked a few times but when I try their solutions it doesn't work.

I have two models, League which has (MLB, NCAAB, NBA, NFL) as options and then I have Team which has all the teams for all the leagues and each team has a league as a foreign key.

How would I create a variable in my view for all the teams under a certain league?
Like, ncaab=Team.objects.select_related('NCAAB')? I know that doesn't work, its just to give an idea of what I need.

```py
    class League(models.Model):
    leagues = (
        ('MLB', ('MLB')),
        ('NBA', ('NBA')),
        ('NCAAB', ('NCAAB')),
        ('NFL', ('NFL')),
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=leagues, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
    league = models.ForeignKey(
        'League', null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer waiting for a response.

teams = Team.objects.filter(league__name='NCAAB')

Found it here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/